# linq where Contains in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, contains

```
//\\ ---- selected items from ChechBoxList
IEnumerable<int> selSender = (from ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                                       where item.Selected
                                       select Convert.ToInt32(item.Value));

//\\ --- linq query
var messages = from m in myEntities.Messages
select new {
m.Id,
m.MessageText,
m.CreatedByUserID
};
```

my problem is: i need to get data filtered by selected items from CheckBoxList "selSender"
I tried the following:

```
 RadGrid1.DataSource = messages.Where(m => selSender.Contains(m.CreatedByUserID));
```

But it's not working, error message:

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable

How can i get data contains based on selSender id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like property `CreatedByUserID` has type of `Nullable<int>`. You need to use it's value for verifying if selSender contains it:

```
RadGrid1.DataSource = from m in myEntities.Messages                          
                      where m.CreatedByUserID.HasValue &&
                            selSender.Contains(m.CreatedByUserID.Value)
                      select new { 
                          m.Id,
                          m.MessageText,
                          m.CreatedByUserID 
                      };
```

Comment: I think this works great, but in my case i need to use
   selSender.Contains(m.CreatedByUserID)
outside the linq query

I tried:

    RadGrid1.DataSource = from mes in messages where selSender.Contains(mes.CreatedByUserID) select mes;

get error:
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int?>'

Comment: @user1450667 Linq query is not executed until you request results of query (e.g. by using foreach, or calling ToList). So, in your case query is not executed before you apply `.Where`. It will be executed only inside `RadGrid.DataSource` setter.